# error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'armadillo.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

I facing this error (which I thought that I know what it means):

> error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'armadillo.lib'

It appears by itself when I opened my project to work on after a weekend (it was working before). I have ever use the **armadillo** library. I did the following attempts to the solve the problem:

- Check all dependencies project by project and any other linked project.
- Searched for 'armadillo' in all projects folder (by applying search in contents option from Windows search).

And I did not get even one result about **armadillo**.

**My question is:** How can I trace which project is looking for **armadillo**? Is there something I have missed?

I am using MSVS 2013, Windows 10

Comment: @Danh yes and It says that front-end project which is asking for it. Which is just a simple console project that call the others

Comment: @Danh All other projects are static libs. And there is no other errors in the main project..